# Get embed tweet widget with react.js

Tags: reactjs, twitter

I am going to show embed tweet data on the react project.
In publish.twitter.com, they show that publish code about embed tweet.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" data-tweet-limit="3">Tweets by twitterDev</a> 
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But in react project, it doesn't work, only shows `<a>`tag -`Tweets by twitterDev`.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
    document.getElementsByClassName("lists")[0].appendChild(script);
}, []);
```

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" data-tweet-limit="3">Tweets by twitterDev</a>
```

Hope to your business will be good.